# How to test the hypothesis "2d points with the same color lie on the same curves"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have a collection of $N$ points in $\Bbb R ^2 $. I don't know how these points were "generated" (i.e I don't have a model for the distribution of the points. They seem more or less uniform, maybe Gaussian with a relatively diagonal covariance). The points are colored by a set of $n$ colors. I don't know as well what is the coloring mechanism.

By visual inspection, it seems to me that many points with the same color form into 1 dimensional structures (=curves, not necessarily straight). But I want to be more rigorous. I would like to give the hypothesis "points with the same color lie on curves" a p-value or any other significance measure.

Also, I would like to ask the same question for each individual color: "Green points lie on one curve".

(I understand the inherit problem that any random collection of points always traces a curve... So I guess I'm talking about smooth curves...)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Regression can be useful for your problem, but you need to define a family of curves to fit your points. For example, you could try to fit a polynomial to them.

In regression you can per form a test - in fact, most statistical packages automatically perform an F-test when doing regression analysis. The F-test can roughly be interpreted with the null hypothesis of the points fitting a curve in the family.